# Form array validation with class

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have form with implemented form array but here i can not validate basically i do not know how to get controls from form array. I have an error that controls of undefined.

Here you can see my code what i have tried

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">

    <div formArrayName="addresses" >
        <div *ngFor="let address of myForm.controls.addresses.controls; let i=index" class="panel panel-default">

            <div [formGroupName]="i" class="myform">
                <label>street</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="street" [class.valid]="address.street.valid"><br><br>
                <label>postcode</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="postcode">
            </div><br><br>
        </div>
    </div><br><br>
        <pre>form value: <br>{{myForm.value | json}}</pre>
</form>
```

you can see full working example here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r4jruv?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are accessing `street` directly from `address` but it's actually in `address.controls`

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">

<div formArrayName="addresses" >
    <div *ngFor="let address of myForm.controls.addresses.controls; let i=index" class="panel panel-default">

        <div [formGroupName]="i" class="myform">
            <label>street</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="street" [class.valid]="address.controls.street.valid"><br><br>
            <label>postcode</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="postcode">
        </div><br><br>
    </div>
</div><br><br>
    <pre>form value: <br>{{myForm.value | json}}</pre>
</form>
```

this should work

Answer (score 1):

First, add a getter to your component to shorten the access path for your `FormArray` controls.

**component.ts**

```
fa: FormArray;

ngOnInit() {
  const fa = this._fb.array([
    this.initAddress(),
  ]);

  this.fa = fa;

  this.myForm = this._fb.group({
    addresses: fa
  });
}
```

Next, update the html

**component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let address of fa.controls; let i=index" class="panel panel-default">
  <div [formGroupName]="i" class="myform">
    <label>street</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="street" [class.valid]="address.valid"><br><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n2qn3j)

Comment: Yes this is also working perfect thank you @Tomasz Kula

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the form control status :

```
<input ... [class.valid]="address.status === 'VALID'">
```

[Here is an edit of your stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-49976864)

Comment: But here i can not track the status like touched and dirty. Is it possible.

Comment: You could use `address.pristine` and `address.dirty`. I edited the stackblitz.

Comment: As suggested by @Tomas Kula, using `address.valid` is better.

Comment: So it is not possible track touched using staus method. Anyway i am going to use @Waleed answer Thank you @ ibenjelloun for your help.